# R: Finding patterns across multiple columns- possibly duplicated()?

Tags: r

I am trying to isolate entries in a dataframe which share common values: see below to reconstruct a portion of my df:

```
Stand<-c("MY","MY","MY","MY","MY")
Plot<-c(12,12,12,12,12)
StumpNumber<-c(1,2,3,3,7)
TreeNumber<-c(1,2,3,4,8)
sample<-data.frame(Stand,Plot,StumpNumber,TreeNumber)
sample
```

And get an output that tells me which entries have common values.  In other words, to quickly isolate situations where there is more than one TreeNumber (or more than one row) for a given Stand,Plot,StumpNumber combination. In the example code that would be that StumpNumber 3 has TreeNumber 3 and TreeNumber 4.

My understanding of duplicated() is that can find instances where duplicated values occur within a single column- what can I do to find situations where a common combination of columns occurs?

Thanks.

Comment: No, what's unique is the combination of Stand, Plot, StumpNumber, and TreeNumber.  I'm a forester and what I'm looking at is situations where multiple trees come from one stump (i.e., trees growing in a clump).

Comment: I wasn't clear. I was asking if TreeNumber is unique _within_ Stand, Plot, StumpNumber.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Description of `?duplicated` indicates that it works on rows of data.frames and the fourth paragraph of the Details section says:

```
 The data frame method works by pasting together a character
 representation of the rows separated by ‘\r’, so may be imperfect
 if the data frame has characters with embedded carriage returns or
 columns which do not reliably map to characters.
```

How did you come to understand that it only works on single columns?

Assuming `TreeNumber` is unique within `Stand`, `Plot`, and `StumpNumber` you just need to exclude it from the call to `duplicated`.

```
> duplicated(sample[,1:3])
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> duplicated(sample[,1:3], fromLast=TRUE)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

---

Update - If you would like all the duplicated rows, you could do something like:

```
> allDups <- duplicated(sample[,1:3],fromLast=TRUE) | duplicated(sample[,1:3])
> sample[allDups,]
  Stand Plot StumpNumber TreeNumber
3    MY   12           3          3
4    MY   12           3          4
```

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, I'm going to assume you have a nesting scheme going on. So, let's say `Trees` are nested in `Stumps`, `Stumps` in `Plots`, and `Plots` in `Stands`. I also assumed the problem you're trying to solve is that some trees are attached to the same stump, which means the problematic entries are those where `Stand`/`Plot`/`Stump` identifiers are repeated for different `TreeNumber`s

What I did was:

- Order the data
- Wrap a slightly customized function around `duplicated()`
- Use `ddply()` (in the `plyr` package) to split and analyze your data
- Print out the problematic entries

#### Ordering the Data

I ordered first by `Stand`, then `Plot`, and finally `StumpNumber`

```
    sampleOrdered <- sample[order(sample$Stand, sample$Plot, sample$StumpNumber)]
```

#### Wrapping my own `duplicated()` function

Assuming the issue is that some trees are attached to the same stump, we can write the following function:

```
    findTreesAttachedToTheSameStump <- function(data) {
        x <- duplicated(data[ , "StumpNumber"])
        data[x, ]
    }
```

This function will select out and return (implicitly) whatever entries pass the `duplicated()` test.

#### Using ddply

I did a bit of [split-apply-combine](http://had.co.nz/plyr/plyr-intro-090510.pdf) here. I instruct `ddply` to break the dataset by `Stand` and `Plot` (since your data is nested, and `StumpNumber` might only be unique within a plot). Then, I apply the function we created above:

```
    sampleDuplicated <- ddply(sampleOrdered, .(Stand, Plot), findTreesAttachedToTheSameStump)
```

#### Print out the problematic stumps

Now all we need to do is call `sampleDuplicated`, which contains the entries for every Plot/Stand/Stump combination that was repeated.

Comment: ...or you could use `sample[duplicated(sample[,1:3]),]`

Comment: @Joshua - Do you mean that would work in place of my solution? I tried just running your line, but I get this output: `<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`. Can you clarify your suggestion?

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure what to tell you.  It "works for me" (tm) in a fresh session on a fresh install of R-2.12.0.  I just run the 5 lines from Nan's question and the one line from my comment to get the same results as your answer.